# Why does it mean when a flag is rejected with "aware of content that requires intervention"?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging, moderators, low-quality

In a similar approach of [slhck's problem](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4515/flagging-posts-that-answer-the-question-with-something-the-op-has-already-dismis) I thought that being very descriptive instead of just clicking *not an answer* would help, but instead I got a new flag reason returned:

[image]

I don't feel like the rejection reason makes sense to me, because my flag reason *tells  the exact opposite of that*.

Comment: Please link to the flagged post.

Comment: Do what I did. *user mentions in the question this does not work. DO NOT REJECT THIS FLAG FOR TECHNICAL INACCURACIES IT HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH THAT!!!!!!!!!!* Works like a charm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another moderator has told me on chat that this post is being protected because of its upvotes.

I'm resting my case and [requesting general clarification on "not an anwer" flags in a new meta question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4735/when-is-an-answer-eligible-to-be-flagged-as-not-an-answer-what-to-do)...

Answer (score 4):

Use your votes to indicate a wrong answer. Drop a comment and mention it doesn't answer the question or why it's not an answer.

Moderators aren't supposed to judge for technical inaccuracies, if a post is egregiously bad or not an answer ("lol, u dunno ip.ha") such flags are accepted and posts are deleted. Else it's left alone.

Comment: To add onto that, if an answer's been downvoted into oblivion already and is just a broken window, sure we'll delete it. But the answer in question was _reasonable_ even if it wasn't perfect, and had a lot of upvotes. It wasn't bad enough to warrant moderator intervention.

Comment: It is wrong for non-technical reasons is the point, I think it is understood that mods should not go deleting answers just because they are inaccurate.

Comment: @soandos: http://superuser.com/a/414051/9666

Comment: @TomWijsman, what is the point you are trying to make? (Note: not sure if you are linking to a deleted post, I can't see those (yet))

Comment: @TomWijsman .. and what part of that is not an answer? Does it say why it's happening? Yes. Does it go on describing? no. That's where the downvotes & comments come in.

Comment: @soandos it's not deleted..

Comment: @TomWijsman Words fail me. Keep up your brilliant work.

Comment: @TomWijsman you're being immature. It's pretty standard in cases where an answer is somewhat lacking to leave a comment asking them to edit it and improve the answer, but not to remove it. Flagging a post does not entitle you to the decision you're asking for.

Comment: I'll give Tom that the answer does not explain *why* (what the OP asked for), but just repeats what the OP already sees, albeit in a different wording. The question is now whether that (including the fact that the answer is remarkably short) warrants a deletion/conversion to comment, or not.

Comment: @nhinkle: This is nothing about being immature, I just really don't understand how "not an answer" flags work anymore. Asking for why it has been rejected I just get an obvious answer here instead of any reasoning of why the moderators have chosen to reject it, which makes it even less understandable. Because the descriptive text that the system has put under the "not an answer" flag radio button makes my flag legit. This is inconsistent with how moderators act upon the flag so I see room for improvement...