# When should I flag something as "very low quality"?

Tags: support, flagging

The answer I am wondering about: [Why is windows not able to create a system partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/444141/why-is-windows-not-able-to-create-a-system-partition/546620#546620)

This answer does not apply to the question asked, and is not very good quality. I flagged it as low quality, and the flag was declined. Should I flag it as not an answer? It is not helpful, but how should I flag it?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### When should I flag as "very low quality"?

Here are the important rules:

- Do not use this flag as "I don't like that post".
- Use the "very low quality" flag only for posts that, for example, read like:

  > u ned put foo bar clik link blow it solv ur pr0bzelm!
  >   regrs

  Basically, anything that can *not* be salvaged through editing because it's not understandable, terribly poor English, or lacks formatting, and just needs to be deleted. It's not the "one flag fits all" thing, but if nobody could rescue that post, it'll have to go.
- Do not flag answers that are wrong or technically incorrect.
- Do not flag questions that need to be closed as "very low quality". If there's a matching close reason, choose that instead. If not, and the post is otherwise readable, let it be.

#### What to do if you think an answer is wrong

- Leave a comment explaining exactly what's wrong.
- Downvote. (That's what these votes are for. Moderators shouldn't judge whether posts are technically correct or not.)

Comment: If it has negative rep, I believe high-rep users can vote to delete after some time (so it doesn't continue to clutter up the question).

Comment: Correct. We don't have too many users capable of doing so, but it does happen. Also note that there are badges for deleting your own negatively scored post. Granted, it's unlikely the poster of this answer will ever return, but they probably had a reason to come here and share a solution that worked for them.

Comment: What about flagging it as `not an answer`? I know, it answers something (that the options provided didn't work for him/her), but that's rather a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: @TFM It attempts to answer the question, saying what worked for them to solve the problem (as they saw it). So it shouldn't be flagged as that: [When is an answer eligible to be flagged as “not an answer”? What to do?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4735/when-is-an-answer-eligible-to-be-flagged-as-not-an-answer-what-to-do/4737#4737)